# Is there a way to Serialize Json that contains a field that contains more json as a string to XML

Tags: c#, json, xml, json.net

I receive Json-data from an external source. I need to convert the Json messages to XML.

This is relatively simple using the NewtonSoft library:

```
        var placeHolder = $"{{\"Data\":  {jsonContent} }} ";
        var xmlNode = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(placeHolder, "Root").OuterXml;
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xmlNode);
```

There is one little odd thing about the Json that I receive that breaks this entire process.

The Json looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "Type": "Application",
    "Object": {
      "Duration": 2,
      "Request": {
        "authReference": "..",
        "IdEnrolment": {
          "username": "test",
          "password": "***",
          "createNewUser": false
        }
      },
      "Type": "XXX.SomeController",
      "Logs": [

      ],
      "Method": "IdEnrolments",
      "Response": {
        "IdUsername": null,
        "result": {
          "resultCode": 0,
          "resultTitle": null,
          "resultMessage": null
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "Type": "Proxy",
    "Object": {
      "Assembly": null,
      "Policy": null,
      "Cache": null,
      "Duration": 516,
      "Request": "{\"AuthenticateUserRequest\":{\"EnterpriseContext\":{\"ContextInfo\":{\"@xmlns\":\"http://example.xom\",\"ProcessContextId\":\"adad\",\"ExecutionContextId\":\"adac\"}\"}}",
      "Type": "https://someserver/services/ent/informationandtechnologymanagement/company/v1",
     "Logs": [

      ],
      "Method": "AuthenticateUser",
      "Response": "{\"AuthenticateUserResponse\":{\"EnterpriseContext\":{\"ContextInfo\":{\"@xmlns\":\"http://example.com\",\"ProcessContextId\":\"adad\",\"ExecutionContextId\":\"adad\"}}}}"
    }
  }
]
```

The first object in the array is perfect and serializes correctly. The second object in the array causes chaos (understandably). The Request and Response fields for this object are actually Strings and they contain the JSON code.

Is there a way to deserialize this properly? I realize that it is a lot to ask from a library to be flexible enough to do this - but I'm just a little stumped at how to use this.

All the messages I receive look roughly the same - but specifically the content of the Request and Response objects are different depending on the specific request/response.

The guys who built this do not have any sort of Schema or contract in place, other than the fact that they send Json text around and they seem unwilling or unable to change how the Json is created.

Any advice will really be appreciated.

**Note:** It seems that the behavior isn't random. Whether I get a proper object or a string is determined by the attribute:  **"Type": "Application"**. There are many different "Types" - and some are properly serialized and others not....  Aaarrggghhh!!!! Frustration !!!!

Comment: *deserialize this properly* what does properly mean? As you have already stated `Request` is a string that contains json, so properly is to deserialise this to a string. If you then want to turn this string into an object then you need to run a second deseialisation on that string

Comment: There are many libraries that convert XML to JSON and vice versa. They all do it slightly differently, and none of them does exactly what you want in every possible case. You need to get used to the idea that you're going to have to customise the conversion by pre-processing the input or post-processing the output.

Comment: @Liam, you are technically correct about the string being deserialized into a string, but that field is a string because someone built the JSON incorrectly to being with. So, my view of 'proper' was the object view. That's what the JSON 'should have looked like'. I wasn't having a jab at the serializers, I was actually just looking for a solution.

Comment: @Michael Kay, I was hoping that one of the many JSON serializers might already deal with this, but, the pre-processing and dual-serialization approach might be the only option left. I just didn't want to do that if someone more clever had a better idea... Thanks for the response though guys. Much appreciated.

Comment: Well then the answer is to "build the JSON" correctly in the first place then

Comment: @Michael Kay Words of wisdom: "You need to get used to the idea that you're going to have to customise the conversion by pre-processing the input or post-processing the output."   I got over it and simply ran HtmlDecode on the body of the string, which turns it into proper JSon text. Works like a charm - and at the cost of 2 lines of code.   Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is bricked in root/Type:Proxy/Object/ the Request-nesting is malformed:

```
 "Request": "{\"AuthenticateUserRequest\":{\"EnterpriseContext\":{\"ContextInfo\":{\"@xmlns\":\"http://example.xom\",\"ProcessContextId\":\"adad\",\"ExecutionContextId\":\"adac\"}\"}}",
```

Here you have 4 curly brackets open, but only 3 that close.

Comment: That was just a typo on my side when I reduced the significantly large JSON message to something that could be posted, so the curly bracket isn't the problem, the deserialization is.

Comment: @MulciberCoder Do you know what toolkit was used to serialize the JSON? If you do I suggest you use it to deserialize the JSON becauase many TKs work slightly dfferent from eachother, so you sometimes het a scenario where you cant deserialize the JSON. (Sorry for my wrong answer earlier)

Comment: @MulciberCoder I noticed that in one sample the request is given as a string and in the other it is a JSON object… you will need to make two seperate structs for that and then parse the string of the specified struct again. Also you will have to take care of XXX.SomeController somehow since that one isnt a legal "Type" assunimg you can enter any number for each 'X'

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you have to handle is very very irregular and bad, so that you just have to deconstuct all of that into C# interfaces, classes, and structs like so:

```
#region Fields
enum JsonObjType 
{
    Application,
    Proxy,
    SomeController,
}
#endregion

#region Classes
// Application
public class AppObj : JsonObjMaster
{
    public readonly JsonObjType Type_Ind {get;}
    public int Duration {get; set;}
    public AppRequest Request {get; set;}
    public AppObjController Controller {get; set;}

    //you need a default constuctor for classes, cause else no json parser will work with them
    public AppObj()
    {
        Type_Ind = JsonObjType.Application;
        Duration = 0;
        AppResult = String.Empty;
        Request = new AppRequest();
        Controller = new AppObjController();
    }
}

public class AppObjController : JsonObjSlave
{
    public readonly JsonObjType Type_Ind {get;}
    public string[] Logs {get; set;}
    public Func</*whatever is supposed to be here*/> Method {get; set;}
    public AppResult Result {get; set;}

    public AppObjController()
    {
        Type_Ind = JsonObjType.SomeController;
        Log = Array.Empty<string>();
        Method = (/*whatever is supposed to be here*/) => null; //may need to change depending on what the function is for
        Result = new AppResult();
    }
}

// Proxy
public class ProxyObj : JsonObjMaster
{
    public readonly JsonObjType Type_Ind {get;}
    public int Duration {get; set;}
    public string Assembly {get; set;}  //I am assuming strings here since no type is supplied
    public string Policy {get; set;}
    public string Cache {get; set;}
    public string Request {get; set;}
    public string Type {get; set;}
    public string[] Logs {get; set;}
    public Func</*whatever is supposed to be here*/> Method {get; set}
    public string Response {get; set;}

    public ProxyObj()
    {
        Type_Ind = JsonObjType.Proxy;
        Duration = 0; //not needed but to stay consistent
        Assembly = String.Empty();
        Policy = String.Empty();
        Cache = String.Empty();
        Request = String.Empty();
        Type = String.Empty();
        Logs = Array.Empty<string>();
        Method = (/*whatever is supposed to be here*/) => null; //may need to change depending on what the function is for
        Response = String.Empty();
    }
}
#endregion

#region Structs
// Interfaces
public interface JsonObjMaster
{
    public readonly JsonObjType Type_Ind {get;}
    public int Duration {get; set;}
}

public interface JsonObjSlave
{
    public readonly JsonObjType Type_Ind {get;}
}

// Structs
public struct IdEnrolment
{
    public string Username {get; set;}
    public string Password {get; set;}
    public bool CreateNewUser {get; set;}
}

public struct AppResult
{
    public int Code {get; set;}
    public string Title {get; set;}
    public string Message {get; set;}
}

public struct AppRequest
{
    public string AuthRefernece {get; set;}
    public IdEnrolment {get; set;}
}
#endregion
```

In order to load the JSON into the classes you now need to supply the parer with the names of the C# object properties in the context of the JSON file so that the parser can link them. This can look something like this:

```
[MyJsonparser.JsonName("Type")]
public string Type {get; set;}
```

But it is highly dependant on the JSON lib you're using, so you need to look it up in their docs.

If you can sucsessfully convert the JSON fuckery that someone (hopefully not you) did into C# objects you can then **resolve the JSON strings that are left over by moving to another layer of classes and structs**, which you can then use for processing.

Now after you have that JSON as C# ocjects you can easily serialize it to XML but sadly because of how bad the JSON is implemented you wont be able to do it automatically without using C# objects as a meta-medium.

Comment: Agreed. Ideally, I would define strongly typed objects and then just serialize in and out of them (even if I have to parse twice). Unfortunately, the one field already has 1500 different structures contained in it. So, I would have to have thousands of little POCO classes. All I needed to achieve in this case was to convert the json to xml - so even if I built those classes, I wouldn't use them for anything else. Also, it breaks the idea of flexibility. If there are already 1500 different structures, 1501 is likely just days away.

Comment: Carannante. Just FYI.... Fully agreed about how bad this Json is and NO - I didn't create it. The messes I make are often much more innovative....

Comment: @MulciberCoder What just came to my mind is that you can also deserialize the JSON to objects and then have a filter fuction that takes in every field with the type string and then tells wether it needs additional deserialization, based on name patterns and whatever you can find. Then take the original JSON and replace the string with the actual object and deserialize again. Afterwards you can serialize that whole affair as XML again